# How can I send or assign one input to multiple names in html?

Tags: html

Hi I have a simple question that I haven't been able to find the answer for. I have two fields in my CRM that I want to map to the user input in a form. How can I send it to both fields? Currently the below code only sends it to "dayphone".

```
<fieldset><input name="dayphone" name="eveningphone" type="number" 
autofocus="" placeholder="phone" /></fieldset>
```

Comment: If you want same value for two fields then you can also copy the posted data server side. By this way user can not manipulate the values of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to add the value of the input field to a hidden input field.

**Jquery**

```
$('#phoneOne').change(function() {
      $('#phoneTwo').val($(this).val());
});
```

**Hidden input field**

```
<fieldset>
  <input name="dayphone" id="phoneOne" type="number" autofocus="" placeholder="phone" />
  <input name="eveningphone" id="phoneTwo" type="hidden" />
</fieldset>
```

This way it will only display one input field but two fields will be posted when you submit the form.

Also I know your tags specified HTML, but you simply can't do this in HTML alone you need some sort of scripting language (I chose Jquery)